# "Simulating" a large number of regressions with different predictor values

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following data and I'm interested in examining some counterfactuals. In particular, I want to examine whether there would be changes in predicted income given a change in income. The best way I can think to do this is to write a loop that runs this regression 1:n. However, how do I also make adjustments to the data frame while running through the loop. I'm really hoping that there is a base R function or something in a package that someone can point me to.

```
df = data.frame(year=c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2009,2010),
                income=c(100,50,70,80,50,40,60,100,90,80),
                age=c(26,30,35,30,28,29,31,34,20,35),
                gpa=c(2.8,3.5,3.9,4.0,2.1,2.65,2.9,3.2,3.3,3.1))
df

mod = lm(income ~ age + gpa, data=df)
summary(mod)
```

Here are some counter factuals that may be worth considering when looking at the relationship between age, gpa, and income.

```
# What is everyone in the class had a lower/higher gpa?
df$gpa2 = df$gpa + 0.55
# what if one person had a lower/higher gpa?
df$gpa2[3] = 1.6
# what if the most recent employee/person had a lower/higher gpa?
df[10,4] = 4.0
```

With or without looping, what would be the best way to "simulate" a large (1000+) number of regression models in order examine various counter factuals, and then save those results in some data structure? Is there a "counter factual" analysis package which could save me a bit of work?

Comment: Is there any common structure to the counter-factuals? What is the baseline `for` loop over?

Comment: the common structure and baseline is take each of the two most recent observation (2009 and 2010), then subtract 1.5 values from each value, then make one point incremental increases each loop until 1.5 gpa point above the current gpa.